# Estimating number of people in a group based on knowing the number of birthdays for today

Tags: probability, birthday

Lets say there is a group of people and we don't know how big is this group.

Lets say that we are told that 3 people had a birthday today.

For simplicity we can assume that birthdays are uniformly distributed and there is 365 days in a year.

Can I, based on this information only, estimate the number of people in this group?

Putting it other way I would like to answer the questions:

```
Given that 3 people had a birthday today what is the probability that the group has 100 people?

Given that 3 people had a birthday today what is the probability that the group has 251 people?
```

So lets `X` be a random variable representing a number of people in a group then

```
P(X = x | number_of_people_who_had_birthday_today = n)
```

is a probability of a group being of size x given number of the people having birthday today is n.

It is obvious that:

```
P(X = 0 | number_of_people_who_had_birthday_today = 3) = 0
P(X = 1 | number_of_people_who_had_birthday_today = 3) = 0
P(X = 2 | number_of_people_who_had_birthday_today = 3) = 0
```

since because 3 people had a birthday there must be at least 3 people in this  group.

I would like to find formula for P. But, I struggle to put my head around it.

---

If I would somehow be able to model the initial number of people in a room as some distribution with a given mean \mu. Lets say I would be coming back on some number of consecutive days and asking how many people had birthday today. Lets say that after 5 days I would get a list of answers [2,3,2,3,4].

I believe that I could use my initial distribution and the above list to somehow update my initial believe using Bayes theorem. But for that I would need P(N | x)(if I am not mistaken) but I don't know what it is.

Comment: There is no upper limit to the group size. We could have a group with a million people, of which $3$ were born today, and everyone else had different birthdays. With $1095$ people, you guarantee that there is at least one day with $3$ or more birthdays. I think you're asking about something else.

Comment: Depends on circumstances. a) You ask a crowd that everybody raise their hand who has birthday today; if there are three, then we *expect* $3\cdot 265$ people in the crowd - unless birthday kids have a different probability of being in the crowd (lower because they rather party at home than be here, or higher because this pace is a goto place for birthday parties); b) One day you are surprised by the large amount of cakes in your firm's kitchen and learn that this is because today three colleages have their birthday; this being an execptional maximum (?), we expect a different estimate

Comment: @DreiCleaner I will remove mention of upper limit if it is confusing I added it since I thought it will be helpful. I simply wonder if based on knowing how many people had a birthday today can I get some insights into the size of the group.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry, I don't think I follow. The whole population is in a closed big room, no one can stay at home. No one can leave no one can get in. It is dark I cant count them, they cant count themselves. All I can do is to ask them how many of them had a birthday today. They tell me 4. Can I use this information to estimate how many of them are locked up in the room? aka what is probability that there is 100 of them? what is probability there are 251 of them?

Comment: I don't think theres an upper limit except the total population. Suppose , somehow we estimate that the upper bound is $n$ no. of people. But then there can be a group of $n+1$ people where the extra person has a birthday different than the present day unless of course all the world population is included in the group. So I simply say the upper estimate is the whole population :)

Answer (score 3):

In the classical statistics formulation of this, you're asking the wrong question.  You can't ask for the probability that there are $m$ people in the room unless you have an
a priori distribution for the number of people there (in which case you can use Bayes' theorem).  What the classical statistician may ask is, what is an [unbiased estimator](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimator) for the number of people in the room?   That is:

Let $M$ be the number of people in the room, and $X$ the number of these whose birthday is today.  For simplicity, I'll neglect February 29, and suppose that each person independently chooses a birthday among $365$ possibilities, with equal probabilities.  Then $\widehat{M} = 365 X$ is the [minimum variance unbiased estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-variance_unbiased_estimator) of $M$ that depends only on $X$.

Of course, in real life things are somewhat messier.  Not all days are equally likely to be birthdays (e.g. there is seasonal dependence, and there are relatively few births on holidays and weekends, because elective Caesarians will not be scheduled then).

Comment: is this saying that the best estimate of the total number of people, given $3$ have birthdays today, is $3\times365=1095$?

Comment: I agree. I struggle a bit with the amount of details I put in to the question so it wont get too hard to understand. You mention Bayes theorem. So what If I would model the initial population somehow with a mean of lets say 100(I don know what distribution). Then I would keep on coming one day and note how many pppl have birthday and then come back on the second day and note and lets say after 5 days I would get a list [2,3,3,2,5]. How can I use Bayes theorem to update my believe about a rel number of people in a room?

Comment: You would compute the conditional probabilities $P(2,3,3,2,5 \mid M=m)$ (using multinomial distribution) of getting those five results given there are $m$ people in the room.  Then if $P(M=m)$ is the a priori probability of having $m$ people in the room, Bayes says
$$ P(M = m \mid 2,3,3,2,5) = \frac{P(2,3,3,2,5 \mid M=m) P(M=m)}{\sum_{k=1}^{100} P(2,3,3,2,5 \mid M=k) P(M=k)}$$